# Efficient Algorithm to obtain Points in a Circle around a Center

Tags: c++, algorithm, canvas, geometry, distance

### Problem

I want to get all pixels that are within a circle of a given radius about a given point, where points can only have **integer coordinates**, i.e. pixels in a canvas.

[image: Illustration]

So I want to obtain all points in the yellow area given `(x, y)` and `r`.

### Approaches

The most efficient way I can think of is to loop through a square around `(x, y)` and check the *Euclidean distance* for each point:

```cpp
for (int px = x - r; px <= x + r; px++) {
  for (int py = y - r; py <= y + r; py++) {
    int dx = x - px, dy = y - py;

    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r) {
      // Point is part of the circle.
    }
  }
}
```

However, this means that this algorithm will check `(r * 2)^2 * (4 - pi) / 4` pixels that are not part of the circle. `dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r`, which seems rather expensive, is called redundantly almost `1 / 4` of the time.

Integrating something like what was [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227057/6509751) might enhance performance:

```cpp
for (int px = x - r; px <= x + r; px++) {
  for (int py = y - r; py <= y + r; py++) {
    int dx = abs(x - px), dy = abs(y - py);

    if (dx + dy <= r || (!(dx > r || dy > r) && (dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r))) {
      // Point is part of the circle.
    }
  }
}
```

However as the author themselves pointed out, this is likely not going to be faster when most of the points are going to be inside of the circle (especially because of `abs`), which `pi / 4` are in this case.

---

I was not able to find any resources on this question. I am looking specifically for a solution in C++ and not something [in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36358188/6509751).

Comment: Integer multiplication and addition is pretty fast. I'm not sure adding a bunch of extra comparisons will help, specially because of all the possible branch prediction misses it might introduce.

Comment: Question asking the "The most" or "The best" usually can't be definitively answered because there is rarely a single best answer. Which solution is best can vary based on the actual use case and architecture it will run on.

Comment: Take advantage of the fact that knowing the range of x values for a given y value gives you insight into the ranges of x values for the previous and next y values.

Comment: You should at least be able to break from the loop once you move from the previous point being good to the next point being bad.  At that point you know you've crossed the boundary and there are no more good points left on that line.

Comment: Another option, for making Scotts' example, start at the top or bottom middle, and then loop to the left and to the right until you hit the boundary.  This will mean you inner loops stop as soon as you pass the boundary.

Comment: I think that the binary search improvement the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright here are the benchmarks I promised.

## Setup

I used [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) and the task was to insert all points within the perimiter of the circle into a `std::vector<point>`. I benchmark for a set of radii and a constant center:

```
radii = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000}
center = {100, 500}
```

- language: C++17
- compiler: msvc 19.24.28316 x64
- platform: windows 10
- optimization: O2 (full optimization)
- threading: single threaded execution

The results of each algorithm is tested for correctness (compared against the output of OPs algorithm).

So far the following algorithms are benchmarked:

1. OP's algorithm `enclosing_square`.
2. [My algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551485/6205379) `containing_square`.
3. [creativecreatorormaybenot's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551257/6205379) `edge_walking`.
4. [Mandy007's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550656/6205379) `binary_search`.

## Results

```
Run on (12 X 3400 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x6)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x6)
  L2 Unified 262K (x6)
  L3 Unified 15728K (x1)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                   Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
binary_search/10/manual_time              804 ns         3692 ns       888722
binary_search/20/manual_time             2794 ns        16665 ns       229705
binary_search/50/manual_time            16562 ns       105676 ns        42583
binary_search/100/manual_time           66130 ns       478029 ns        10525
binary_search/200/manual_time          389964 ns      2261971 ns         1796
binary_search/500/manual_time         2286526 ns     15573432 ns          303
binary_search/1000/manual_time        9141874 ns     68384740 ns           77
edge_walking/10/manual_time               703 ns         5492 ns       998536
edge_walking/20/manual_time              2571 ns        49807 ns       263515
edge_walking/50/manual_time             15533 ns       408855 ns        45019
edge_walking/100/manual_time            64500 ns      1794889 ns        10899
edge_walking/200/manual_time           389960 ns      7970151 ns         1784
edge_walking/500/manual_time          2286964 ns     55194805 ns          308
edge_walking/1000/manual_time         9009054 ns    234575321 ns           78
containing_square/10/manual_time          629 ns         4942 ns      1109820
containing_square/20/manual_time         2485 ns        40827 ns       282058
containing_square/50/manual_time        15089 ns       361010 ns        46311
containing_square/100/manual_time       62825 ns      1565343 ns        10990
containing_square/200/manual_time      381614 ns      6788676 ns         1839
containing_square/500/manual_time     2276318 ns     45973558 ns          312
containing_square/1000/manual_time    8886649 ns    196004747 ns           79
enclosing_square/10/manual_time          1056 ns         4045 ns       660499
enclosing_square/20/manual_time          3389 ns        17307 ns       206739
enclosing_square/50/manual_time         18861 ns       106184 ns        37082
enclosing_square/100/manual_time        76254 ns       483317 ns         9246
enclosing_square/200/manual_time       421856 ns      2295571 ns         1654
enclosing_square/500/manual_time      2474404 ns     15625000 ns          284
enclosing_square/1000/manual_time     9728718 ns     68576389 ns           72
```

## Code

The complete test code is below, you can copy & paste it and test it yourself. `fill_circle.cpp` contains the implementation of the different algorithms.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>

#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#include "fill_circle.hpp"

using namespace std::string_literals;

std::unordered_map<const char*, circle_fill_func> bench_tests =
{
    {"enclosing_square", enclosing_square},
    {"containing_square", containing_square},
    {"edge_walking", edge_walking},
    {"binary_search", binary_search},
};

std::vector<int> bench_radii = {10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000};

void postprocess(std::vector<point>& points)
{
    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end());
    //points.erase(std::unique(points.begin(), points.end()), points.end());
}

std::vector<point> prepare(int radius)
{
    std::vector<point> vec;
    vec.reserve(10ull * radius * radius);
    return vec;
}

void bm_run(benchmark::State& state, circle_fill_func target, int radius)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    constexpr point center = {100, 500};

    auto expected_points = prepare(radius);
    enclosing_square(center, radius, expected_points);
    postprocess(expected_points);

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        auto points = prepare(radius);

        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        target(center, radius, points);
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        postprocess(points);
        if (expected_points != points)
        {
            auto text = "Computation result incorrect. Expected size: " + std::to_string(expected_points.size()) + ". Actual size: " + std::to_string(points.size()) + ".";
            state.SkipWithError(text.c_str());
            break;
        }

        state.SetIterationTime(duration<double>(stop - start).count());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (auto [name, target] : bench_tests)
        for (int radius : bench_radii)
            benchmark::RegisterBenchmark(name, bm_run, target, radius)->Arg(radius)->UseManualTime();

    benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
    if (benchmark::ReportUnrecognizedArguments(argc, argv))
        return 1;
    benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
}
```

#### fill_circle.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

struct point
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

constexpr bool operator<(point const& lhs, point const& rhs) noexcept
{
    return lhs.x != rhs.x
               ? lhs.x < rhs.x
               : lhs.y < rhs.y;
}

constexpr bool operator==(point const& lhs, point const& rhs) noexcept
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}

using circle_fill_func = void(*)(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points);

void enclosing_square(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points);
void containing_square(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points);
void edge_walking(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points);
void binary_search(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points);
```

#### fill_circle.cpp

```
#include "fill_circle.hpp"

constexpr double sqrt2 = 1.41421356237309504880168;
constexpr double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643;

void enclosing_square(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points)
{
    int sqr_rad = radius * radius;

    for (int px = center.x - radius; px <= center.x + radius; px++)
    {
        for (int py = center.y - radius; py <= center.y + radius; py++)
        {
            int dx = center.x - px, dy = center.y - py;
            if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= sqr_rad)
                points.push_back({px, py});
        }
    }
}

void containing_square(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points)
{
    int sqr_rad = radius * radius;
    int half_side_len = radius / sqrt2;
    int sq_x_end = center.x + half_side_len;
    int sq_y_end = center.y + half_side_len;

    // handle inner square
    for (int x = center.x - half_side_len; x <= sq_x_end; x++)
        for (int y = center.y - half_side_len; y <= sq_y_end; y++)
            points.push_back({x, y});

    // probe the rest
    int x = 0;
    for (int y = radius; y > half_side_len; y--)
    {
        int x_line1 = center.x - y;
        int x_line2 = center.x + y;
        int y_line1 = center.y - y;
        int y_line2 = center.y + y;

        while (x * x + y * y <= sqr_rad)
            x++;

        for (int i = 1 - x; i < x; i++)
        {
            points.push_back({x_line1, center.y + i});
            points.push_back({x_line2, center.y + i});
            points.push_back({center.x + i, y_line1});
            points.push_back({center.x + i, y_line2});
        }
    }
}

void edge_walking(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points)
{
    int sqr_rad = radius * radius;
    int mdx = radius;

    for (int dy = 0; dy <= radius; dy++)
    {
        for (int dx = mdx; dx >= 0; dx--)
        {
            if (dx * dx + dy * dy > sqr_rad)
                continue;

            for (int px = center.x - dx; px <= center.x + dx; px++)
            {
                for (int py = center.y - dy; py <= center.y + dy; py += 2 * dy)
                {
                    points.push_back({px, py});
                    if (dy == 0)
                        break;
                }
            }

            mdx = dx;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void binary_search(point const& center, int radius, std::vector<point>& points)
{
    constexpr auto search = []( const int &radius, const int &squad_radius, int dx, const int &y)
    {
        int l = y, r = y + radius, distance;

        while (l < r)
        {
            int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            distance = dx * dx + (y - m) * (y - m);
            if (distance > squad_radius)
                r = m - 1;
            else if (distance < squad_radius)
                l = m + 1;
            else
                r = m;
        }

        if (dx * dx + (y - l) * (y - l) > squad_radius)
            --l;

        return l;
    };

    int squad_radius = radius * radius;    
    for (int px = center.x - radius; px <= center.x + radius; ++px)
    {
        int upper_limit = search(radius, squad_radius, px - center.x, center.y);
        for (int py = 2*center.y - upper_limit; py <= upper_limit; ++py)
        {
            points.push_back({px, py});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot np. Please edit this answer if you adjust the algorithms so we can update the results here.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

Based on the idea from [@ScottHunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275), I came up with the following algorithm:

```cpp
#include <functional>

// Executes point_callback for every point that is part of the circle
// defined by the center (x, y) and radius r.
void walk_circle(int x, int y, int r,
                 std::function<void(int x, int y)> point_callback) {
  for (int px = x - r; px < x + r; px++)
    point_callback(px, y);
  int mdx = r;
  for (int dy = 1; dy <= r; dy++)
    for (int dx = mdx; dx >= 0; dx--) {
      if (dx * dx + dy * dy > r * r)
        continue;
      for (int px = x - dx; px <= x + dx; px++) {
        point_callback(px, y + dy);
        point_callback(px, y - dy);
      }
      mdx = dx;
      break;
    }
}
```

### Algorithm explained

This algorithm performs a *minute* number of checks. Specifically, it only checks in each row until the first point that is part of the circle is reached. Furthermore, it will skip points to the left of the previously identified point in the next row. Additionally, by using symmetry, only half of the rows (`n/2 + 1/2` as we start at 0) are checked.

[image: Visualization]

This is a visualization of the algorithm I created. The red outline indicates the square that would have previously been checked and the black pixels indicate the real circle (with the red pixel in the middle being the center). The algorithm checks points (marked blue) and loops through valid points (marked green).
As you can see, the number of blue pixels at the end is minute, i.e. there are only a few points being looped over that are not part of the circle. Additionally, notice that only the first green pixel each time needs a check, the others are only looped through, which is why they appear instantly.

### Notes

The axes could easily be reversed, obviously.

This could be optimized by taking advantage of symmetry even more, i.e. that the rows are going to be the same as the columns (going through all rows is the same as going through all columns, left to right, up to down, vise versa, vise vera) and going down only a quarter of the rows from the center would be enough to determine exactly what points are going to be part of the circle. However, I feel like the minor performance bump this is going to give is not worth the additional code.
If someone wants to code it out, propose an edit to this answer.

### Code with comments

```cpp
#include <functional>

// Executes point_callback for every point that is part of the circle
// defined by the center (x, y) and radius r.
void walk_circle(int x, int y, int r,
                 std::function<void(int x, int y)> point_callback) {
  // Walk through the whole center line as it will always be completely
  // part of the circle.
  for (int px = x - r; px < x + r; px++)
    point_callback(px, y);
  // Define a maximum delta x that shrinks whith every row as the arc
  // is closing.
  int mdx = r;
  // Start directly below the center row to make use of symmetry.
  for (int dy = 1; dy <= r; dy++)
    for (int dx = mdx; dx >= 0; dx--) {
      // Check if the point is part of the circle using Euclidean distance.
      if (dx * dx + dy * dy > r * r)
        continue;

      // If a point in a row left to the center is part of the circle,
      // all points to the right of it until the center are going to be
      // part of the circle as well.
      // Then, we can use horizontal symmetry to move the same distance
      // to the right from the center.
      for (int px = x - dx; px <= x + dx; px++) {
        // Use y - dy and y + dy thanks to vertical symmetry
        point_callback(px, y + dy);
        point_callback(px, y - dy);
      }

      // The next row will never have a point in the circle further left.
      mdx = dx;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: JS is probably fast enough to "brute force" calculate the pixel coordinates on-the-fly for each circle (maybe no optimization needed). But, will you be testing only 1 radius or just a few radii? If yes, you can pre-calculate the internal points of a circle into an array and reuse those calculated points -- offset to the origin of the circle you're testing.

Comment: You can see the last update of my code i think that is better

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimization that reduce 1/4 the dimension of search:

```
for (int px = x; px <= x + r; ++px) {
  bool find = false;
  int dx = x - px, dy;
  for (int py = y; !find && py <= y + r; ++py) {
    dy = y - py;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r)) {
      /* (px, py), (px, y+y-py+r), (x+x-px+r, py) 
       & (x+x-px+r, y+y-py+r) are part of the circle.*/
    }else{
      find = true; //Avoid increasing on the axis y
    }
  }
}
```

or better, improving performance the iteration of second circle `for`   avoiding the `if` conditional

```
for (int px = x; px <= x + r; ++px) {
  int dx = x - px, py = y;
  for (; dx * dx + (py-y) * (py-y) <= r * r; ++py) {
    /* (px, py), (px, y+y-py+r), (x+x-px+r, py) 
     & (x+x-px+r, y+y-py+r) are part of the circle.*/
  }
}
```

well i think that other option is a binary search for upper limit:

```
int binarySearch(int R, int dx, int y){
  int l=y, r=y+R;
  while (l < r) { 
    int m = l + (r - l) / 2;  
    if(dx*dx + (y - m)*(y - m) > R*R) r = m - 1; 
    else if(dx*dx + (y - m)*(y - m) < R*R) l = m + 1; 
    else r = m;
  }
  if(dx*dx + (y - l)*(y - l) > R*R) --l;
  return l;
}

for (int px = x; px <= x + r; ++px) {
  int upperLimit = binarySearch(r, px-x, y);
  for (int py = y; py <= upperLimit; ++py) {
    /* (px, py), (px, y+y-py+r), (x+x-px+r, py) 
     & (x+x-px+r, y+y-py+r) are part of the circle.*/
  }
}
```

The idea of binary search is to find the upper limit optimally,  avoiding  the `if` condition and calculations within the `for` cycle. For this, it is checked which is the largest integer that makes the distance between the current point and the radius within the circle.

PD: Sorry my English.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (line = 1; line <= r; line++) {
   dx = (int) sqrt(r * r - line * line);
   for (ix = 1; ix <= dx; ix++) {
       putpixel(x - ix, y + line)
       putpixel(x + ix, y + line)
       putpixel(x - ix, y - line)
       putpixel(x + ix, y - line)
   } 
}
```

To avoid repeated generation of pixels at axes, it is worth to start loops from 1 and draw central lines (ix==0 or line==0) in separate loop.

Note that there is also pure integer Bresenham algorithm to generate circumference points.

Comment: IThere is no **real** gain of using symmetry here. I changed code to generate a quarter of circle.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, first of all we calculate the **inner square** of the circle. The formula for it is straight forward:

```
x² + y² = r²    // circle formula
2h² = r²        // all sides of square are of equal length so x == y, lets define h := x
h = r / sqrt(2) // half side length of the inner square
```

Now, every point between `(-h, -h)` and `(+h, +h)` lies within the circle. Here is an image of what I mean:

[image: 1]

The remaining blue part is a bit tricky, but not too complicated either. We start at the very top of the blue circle `(x = 0, y = -radius)`. Next, we walk right (`x++`) until we leave the circle perimiter (until `x²+y² < r²` doesn't hold anymore). Everything between (0, y) and (x, y) is within the circle. Because of symmetry we can extend this 8 fold by

- (-x, -y), (+x, -y)
- (-x, +y), (+x, +y)
- (-y, -x), (-y, +x)
- (+y, -x), (+y, +x)

now we go down 1 line (`y--`) and repeat the steps above (while keeping the most recent value of `x`). Add the center of the circle to each of the points and you're done.

Here is a visualization. There are some artifacts because of the upscaling. The red dot shows what we're testing at each iteration:

[image: 1]

Here is the full code (using opencv to draw the stuff):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

constexpr double sqrt2 = 1.41421356237309504880168;

int main()
{
    cv::Point center(200, 200);
    constexpr int radius = 180;

    // create test image
    cv::Mat img(400, 400, CV_8UC3);
    cv::circle(img, center, radius, {180, 0, 0}, cv::FILLED);
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::waitKey();

    // calculate inner rectangle
    int halfSideLen = radius / sqrt2;
    cv::Rect innerRect(center.x - halfSideLen, center.y - halfSideLen, halfSideLen * 2, halfSideLen * 2);
    cv::rectangle(img, innerRect, {0, 180, 0}, cv::FILLED);
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::waitKey();

    // probe the rest
    int x = 0;
    for (int y = radius; y >= halfSideLen; y--)
    {
        for (; x * x + y * y < radius * radius; x++)
        {
            // anything between the following points lies within the circle
            // each pair of points represents a line
            // (-x, -y), (+x, -y)
            // (-x, +y), (+x, +y)
            // (-y, -x), (-y, +x)
            // (+y, -x), (+y, +x)

            // center + {(-X..X) x (-Y..Y)} is inside the circle
            cv::line(img, cv::Point(center.x - x, center.y - y), cv::Point(center.x + x, center.y - y), {180, 180, 0});
            cv::line(img, cv::Point(center.x - x, center.y + y), cv::Point(center.x + x, center.y + y), {180, 180, 0});
            cv::line(img, cv::Point(center.x - y, center.y - x), cv::Point(center.x - y, center.y + x), {180, 180, 0});
            cv::line(img, cv::Point(center.x + y, center.y - x), cv::Point(center.x + y, center.y + x), {180, 180, 0});

            cv::imshow("img", img);
            cv::waitKey(20);
        }
    }

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I think my version should be quicker for anything except very small images because the calculation of the square in the center is constant time (without any trig. functions, we only use basic numerics). This also means that you don't have to perfom **any** checks inside the square. For the rest of the image tha algorithms are basically the same.

Comment: Just noticed that aswell. This might boil down to micro optimizations on assembler level. Maybe I'll do a benchmark later.

Comment: Is there an analytical solution for the number of pixels before running the algorithm?

Comment: @DDuck You can approximate the number of pixels in the circle by calculating its area. The accuracy of that result depends on the algorithm used to draw the circle though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has a fixed complexity of O(n^2) where n is the radius of the circle. The same complexity as a square or any regular 2D shape

There is no getting past the fact that you can not reduce the number of pixels in a circle, even if you take advantage of the symmetry the complexity remains the same.

So ignoring complexity and looking for optimization.

In your question you state that the `abs` is a little too expensive per pixel (or 4th pixel)

### Once per row is better than once per pixel

You can reduce it down to 1 square root per row. For a circle radius 256 that 128 square roots

```
void circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
    int y1 = y, y2 = y + 1, r = 0, rSqr = radius * radius;
    while (r < radius) {
        int x1 = x, x2 = x + 1, right = x + sqrt(rSqr - r * r) + 1.5;;
        while (x2 < right) {
            pixel(x1, y1);
            pixel(x2, y1);
            pixel(x1--, y2);
            pixel(x2++, y2);
        }
        y1--;
        y2++;
        r++;
    }
}
```

To get more out of it you can crate a lookup table for the sqrt root calculations.

### All integer

Alternatively you can use the variation on the [bresenham line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) that replaces the square root with all integer math. However it is a mess and would not be of any benefit unless the device does not have a floating point unit.

```
void circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
    int l, yy = 0, xx = radius - 1, dx = 1, dy = 1;
    int err = dx - (radius << 1);
    int l2 = x, y0 = y, r2 = x + 1;
    int l1 = x - xx, r1 = r2 + xx;
    int y2 = y0 - xx, y1 = y0 + 1, y3 = y1 + xx;
    while (xx >= yy) {
        l = l1;
        while (l < r1) {
            pixel(l, y1);
            pixel(l++, y0);
        }
        l = l2;
        while (l < r2) {
            pixel(l, y3);
            pixel(l++, y2);
        }
        err += dy;
        dy += 2;
        y0--;
        yy++;
        y1++;
        l2--;
        r2++;
        if (err > 0) {
            dx += 2;
            err += (-radius << 1) + dx;
            xx--;
            r1--
            l1++
            y3--
            y2++
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a square that fits inside the circle and it is pretty straightforward to find if the point falls in.

This will solve most points(2 * r^2) in O(1) time, instead of searching all (4 * r^2) points.

**Edit:** For the rest of the points, you don't need to loop all the other pixels. You need to loop for the 4 rectangles sized with dimensions [(2r/sqrt(2)), r-(r/sqrt(2))] on the 4 sides(north,east,south,west) of the square that is inside. It means that you never have to search for the squares on the corners. Since, it is completely symmetric, we can take the absolute values of input points and search if the point is inside half-squares on the positive side of the coordinate plane. Which means we only loop once instead of 4.

```
int square_range = r/sqrt(2);
int abs_x = abs(x);
int abs_y = abs(y);

if(abs_x < square_range && abs_y < square_range){
    //point is in
}
else if(abs_x < r && abs_y < r){  // if it falls in the outer square
    // this is the only loop that has to be done
    if(abs_x < abs_y){
        int temp = abs_y;
        abs_y = abs_x;
        abs_x = temp;
    }
    for(int x = r/sqrt(2) ; x < r ; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y < r/sqrt(2) ; y++){
             if(x*x + y*y < r*r){
                 //point is in
             }
         }    
    }    
}
```

Overall complexity of the code is O((r-r/sqrt(2))* (r/sqrt(2))). Which is only looping for a half of a single rectangle(8 way symmetry) that is in between the inner square and cirle's outer border.

Comment: This approach will draw a square inside circle. What about the rest of circle?

Comment: As I mentioned for the other points that are outside the square will be searched with a loop.

Comment: The overall complexity is `O(n^2)` not the `O((r-r/sqrt(2))* (r/sqrt(2)))` you give  a quadratic and big O notation should not include the coefficients and all but the highest power must be ignored. This problem can not be simplified below `O(n^2)`

Comment: I am aware of big o notation, but my point was to state that this algorithm does less operations compared to other O(n^2).